# Contourplot of complex Roots

Tags: plotting, complex

Suppose I have this equation:

$$ z^2 + 3z + (x^2 + y^2) = 0 $$

I want the real and complex contour plot of $z(x,y)$. Analytically, the real/imaginary boundary is separated by condition $x^2 + y^2 \leq \frac{9}{4}$

The regular contour plot only plots the real parts when I use findRoot:

```
eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0
ContourPlot[ 
 z /. FindRoot[eqn[x, y, z], {z, 1}], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The darkest purple represents the complex area.

How do I obtain contour plots of real roots of z, imaginary roots of z? Also, if possible combine them into a single graph.

Tried this different approach of letting $z = a + bi$, but doesn't work.

```
 z = a + b I;
 eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0
    ContourPlot[ 
     z /. FindRoot[Im[eqn[x, y, z]], {b, 1}], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Plots from **difficult problem**: First one is real, second one is imaginary root contour plot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: ListContourPlot?

Answer (score 2):

How about using `NSolve` like this. As you know z roots are 2-sets. but I have tried the one of things.

```
eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0

opts := Sequence[
   PlotLegends -> Automatic,
   Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 9/4},
   ExclusionsStyle -> Red,
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"];

rec = ContourPlot[
  Re[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  Evaluate@opts, Contours -> 10]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
imc = ContourPlot[
  Im[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
  Evaluate@opts, Contours -> 10]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
ContourPlot[
 If[x^2 + y^2 < 9/4,
  Re[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]],
  Im[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 Evaluate@opts, Contours -> 20
 ]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[
 If[x^2 + y^2 < 9/4,
  Re[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]],
  Im[z] /. NSolve[eqn[x, y, z], z][[1]]], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 Evaluate@opts, Mesh -> 20, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

You can't `Plot` a complex function. But you can always plot the `Re` and `Im` part of the solution.

```
eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0
sol[x_,y_]=z/.Solve[eqn[x,y,z],z]
ContourPlot[Re[sol[x,y]][[2]],{x,0,2},{y,0,2},MaxRecursion->3,PlotLabel->"Real"]
ContourPlot[Im[sol[x,y]][[2]],{x,0,2},{y,0,2},MaxRecursion->3,PlotLabel->"Imaginary"]
```

[image]

similarly you can also plot the other solution.

> EDIT : With `FindRoot`

```
eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0
ContourPlot[z /. FindRoot[eqn[x, y, z], {z, 1. I}, MaxIterations -> 100] //Re, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},PlotLabel -> "Real"]
ContourPlot[z /. FindRoot[eqn[x, y, z], {z, 1. I}, MaxIterations -> 100] //Im, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},PlotLabel -> "Imaginary"]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with FindRoot as well? Because I'm applying it to a more difficult problem that uses FindRoot

Comment: try a complex initial value like `0.+ I` in `FindRoot`.

Comment: Let's say that I can only use FindRoot for my difficult problem. I applied it to this (simpler)problem, and it doesn't seem to work. eqn[x_, y_, z_] := z^2 + 3 z + x^2 + y^2 == 0
ContourPlot[
 z /. FindRoot[eqn[x, y, z], {z, 1.4 I}], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

Comment: @user44840 : you didn't mention `Re` or `Im`, that's you get the plot for only real region and white space for imaginary portion. Have a look at my modified answer.

Comment: Hmm that works! But in the imaginary plot, why are there such rough and random contours? How do you separate which is real and imaginary then? (i.e. identify the boundary). I've uploaded pictures of the real and imaginary contour plots. From the real plot, it seems like there's an imaginary root in some regions, while the imaginary contour plot is a mess.

Comment: when you use `Re` it will return the real part of the value. If the root is purely imaginary, then it will return you zero. So it is already identified. Looking at your x and y value I would say you have to increase `MaxIteration` and `Working Precision`. Right now I can't think about a way figure how to get the boundary, but you can find the region where imaginary part is almost zero (real solution) by `RegionFunction`. `ContourPlot[ z /. FindRoot[eqn[x, y, z], {z, 1.4 I}] // Im, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Abs[z] < 10^-4]]`. You can choose smaller than 10^-4.